# Facebook debug_token only returns is_valid and app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to return the user_id in my app when calling https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/debug_token

The Fields in the return data only returns is_valid and the app_id like this:

```
{
   "data": {
      "app_id": "338666432978837",
      "is_valid": true
   }
}
```

Is there a setting that I am missing in the App setup?

Comment: I am using    GET /debug_token?
 input_token={input-token}&
 access_token={access-token} where input-token is my app-access-token and the access token is the external_access_token

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are debugging your own app access token, this is the reason why you don't get any user specific info - because there is no user in this context.

In order to get user info such as the user's id, you need to debug the user access token:

```
GET /debug_token?
  input_token=THE_USER_TOKEN&
  access_token=YOUR_APP_TOKEN
```

**input_token** The user's token you want to debug.

**access_token** Your app's token. Required for request authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use

```
GET /debug_token?
 input_token={input-token}&
 access_token={access-token}
```

as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#debug

I was able to reproduce this behaviour if the `input_token` parameter is an app access token, so what kind of `input_token` are you using?

Comment: I am using the app-access-token for input_token